# IBM Worklight 6.1.0.1 - Server Configuration Tool issues

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

My configuration is:

- OS: RHEL 5.7
- IBM DB2 10.1
- WAS8.5
- WL6.1.0.1 (last fix pack installed)

When reading the WL6.1 Information Center, it is said that you can deploy several Worklight projects (that is, several project WAR files) to an application server just as you would deploy any JEE application: each deployed project must have a unique name and a unique context path.

This exactly what I am trying to do using the Server Configuration Tool located under the directory '/opt/IBM/Worklight/shortcuts/'.

When deploying the first WAR file under a WebSphere Application server profile, the Server Configuration Tool works perfectly and creates/deploys an EAR file named 'IBM_Worklight_Console.ear', in which the WAR file is included. However, when using the Server Configuration Tool to deploy a new WAR file under the same WebSphere Application server profile, the Server Configuration Tool creates the same EAR file named 'IBM_Worklight_Console.ear' with the new WAR file included. But obviously it overwrites the first Worklight Server configuration, preventing to deploy several Worklight projects to the websphere application server profile as it is supposed to do.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The Worklight documentation, [section "Configuring multiple IBM Worklight projects"](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc%2Fdevref%2Fc_ant_tasks_configuring_multiple_wl_projects.html), says that for multiple Worklight project WAR files in WebSphere Application Server, each must have a different id. In the Worklight Server Configuration Tool, you enter this id in the "Application server configuration" panel, in the "Deployment id" field. Once you choose a different id for each, they will be able to coexist. (At most one of the ids can be left empty.)

Comment: Very good - Thanks for the info. By using the dpeloyment id, indeed it works better. I think the Infocenter is not quite clear about that specific item.

Comment: @user3545696: If the answer resolved your issue, please flag the question as "answered" so that it can benefit others.

Comment: How to flag the question as "answered" ?

Comment: @Olympien1383, there is a check mark icon to the left where it shows "2"